# How to find an example of a non Abelian group of arbitrary finite order? eg. $39$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I was thinking of building on top of known non Abelian groups, like $S_3$, and taking a direct product with $\Bbb Z_n$'s but those groups' order would be a multiple of order of $S_3$.

- So, is there is a clever way to do it for any order, like use an
  Abelian group of order close to, say $39$, and make it non-Abelian?
- Here,
  [Finding presentation of group of order 39](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446826/finding-presentation-of-group-of-order-39)
  they give a general representation but can we come up with an actual
  example without using Sylow theorems? 
  Appreciate your response.

Comment: The answer by pasco to the linked question provides an actual example of a nonabelian group of order $39$, namely the group $\langle x,y \mid x^{13},y^3,y^{-1}xy=x^3 \rangle$. This type of construction is known as a semidirect product.

Comment: If $|G|=pq$ with primes $p\neq q$ with $p\mid q-1$, then there is always a non-abelian group of order $pq$, which is a semidirect product as above, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63219/nonabelian-semidirect-products-of-order-pq?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502186/groups-of-order-pq-are-cyclic). We have $39=pq=3\cdot 13$ and $3\mid 12$.

Comment: Thanks, so semi-direct product of Z13 and Z3 is an example then?

Answer (score 3):

There are composite orders (e.g. 15 or 765, or prime squares) such that all groups of that order will be abelian, and there is no all-purpose construction, but here are a few constructions of nonabelian groups that cover lots of orders:

- If the order is even and $>4$, one can construct a dihedral group.
- If the order involves a prime power $p^k$ such that another prime divisor (that could be $p$ as well, so this in particular covers all orders that are multiples of a prime cubed) that divides the order of $GL_k(p)$, one can form a nonabelian semidirect product.