# Trouble understanding semidirect product of $Z_3$ and $Z_{13}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Here a representation for a non Abelian of order 39 is given
[Finding presentation of group of order 39](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446826/finding-presentation-of-group-of-order-39) by Pisco. Am I correct in understanding that the non-trivial homomorphism in this case is:
$\phi:Z_3 \rightarrow Aut(Z_{13})$ where $\phi_y(x) = yxy^{-1}$  $\forall y\in Z_3$ and $\forall x\in Z_{13}$
For different $y$ we get different Automorphisms in $Z_{13}$.
To find the actual automorphism i.e. to find $i$ s.t. $yxy^{-1} = x^i$, we are using the automorphism corresponding to the generator $y$ of $Z_3$ and $x$ of $Z_{13}$? Appreciate your help in explaining the semidirect product in terms of its explicit definition to help me get used to the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your homomorphism $\phi$ makes no sense to me; in
$$\phi:\ \Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}/13\Bbb{Z}):\ y\ \longmapsto\ (x\ \longmapsto\ yxy^{-1}),$$
how do you multiply elements $y\in\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}$ and $x\in\Bbb{Z}/13\Bbb{Z}$ together? Let me give some background.

---

In stead, identify $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}/13\Bbb{Z})\cong(\Bbb{Z}/13\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ with $\Bbb{Z}/12\Bbb{Z}$ by choosing a primitive root mod $13$, i.e. a generator of the multiplicative group $(\Bbb{Z}/13\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$.

For example, a few calculations show that $2$ is a primitive root mod $13$. Hence every automorphism of $\Bbb{Z}/13\Bbb{Z}$ is determined by where it sends $2$. So every automorphism is of the form
$$\psi:\ \Bbb{Z}/13\Bbb{Z}\ \longmapsto\ \Bbb{Z}/13\Bbb{Z}:\ 2\ \longmapsto\ 2^k,$$
for some $k\in\{1,\ldots,12\}$. Check that this gives an isomorphism
$$\Bbb{Z}/12\Bbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}/13\Bbb{Z}):\ k\ \longmapsto\ (n\ \longmapsto\ n\cdot2^k).$$

---

This makes it clearer what homomorphisms $\phi:\ \Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}/13\Bbb{Z})$ look like. They are determined by where $1\in\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}$ is mapped, and this must be mapped to an element of order dividing $3$. There are only three elements of order dividing $3$ in $\Bbb{Z}/12\Bbb{Z}$, they are $0$, $4$ and $8$. So we have three homomorphisms
$$\phi:\ \Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}/13\Bbb{Z}),$$
and they are of the form
$$\phi(m):\ \Bbb{Z}/13\Bbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{Z}/13\Bbb{Z}:\ n\ \longmapsto\ n\cdot2^{km},$$
for some $k\in\{0,4,8\}$.

Comment: Here $m \in Z/3Z$ right? So, for all $m$, does $\phi$ map $m$ to $n \rightarrow n.2^k$?

Comment: I can't understand how $\phi$ is not a function of $m$.

Comment: @manifolded Oops, I forgot an exponent. I've corrected it now.