# How to construct the homomorphism in semidirect product of $Z_3$ and $Z_{13}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product, automorphism-group

I know that in the semidirect product of $A$ and $B$, the homomorphism $\phi:A\rightarrow Aut(B)$ should be $\phi_y(x) = yxy^{-1}$ but have no idea how to construct one for $\phi:Z_3\rightarrow Aut(Z_{13})$. Any help is appreciated. The presentation of such a group is given here [Finding presentation of group of order 39](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446826/finding-presentation-of-group-of-order-39) but I don't know what the explicit homomorphism would be.

Comment: “Homeomorphism” is a topological term: it means a continuous bijection with continuous inverse. Presumably, you mean **homomorphism**.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3023714/trouble-understanding-semidirect-product-of-z-3-and-z-13).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, corrected that.

Comment: ... not everywhere... but now it’s fixed.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I wanted to know which homomorphism corresponds to the presentation $\{x,y|x^{13}=y^3=1,yxy^{-1} = x^3\}$? And that question answers how to find all the homomorphisms.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks.

Comment: It's $y \mapsto (x\mapsto x^3)$.